# Node.js and socket.io - Access socket from a different file

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

i'm having a problem accessing the socket from a secondary file:

Having two files:
1) main.js
2) secondary.js

In main.js:

```
var sec = require('./secondary.js');    

function DoFuncOnSecondaryFile(){
    setInterval(function(){
        //here i can't pass the socket, because it is not inside "io.on connection"
        sec.myExternalFunc( socket ); 
    }, 5000);
}

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    //all the socket events in here
});
```

In secondary.js:

```
module.exports = {
    myExternalFunc: function(){
        socket.emit("message", "I cannot reach the socket so i will throw an error");
        socket.to(anId).emit("message", "Supposing 'anId' is correctly defined and it is the id of a connected socket, this function won't work anyway!");
    }
}
```

I need the function "myExternalFunc()" to be executed every 5 seconds, if i want to pass the socket as argument, i need to put it inside io.on('connection') so that the socket variable is defined, but then my Interval will start everytime someone connects.
How can I use an emit in an external file where i am not able to pass the socket variable?

Comment: Did you find out how? Though i know passing functional methods might be a way, but do feel it's ugly and not robust.